# LXML querying word document.xml.rels

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to retrieve a specific Relationship tag in the /word/_rels/document.xml.rels file. This file is inside the docx if opened with a zip program.

This is the contents of the rels file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footnotes" Target="footnotes.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId13" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer2.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId18" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header5.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/customXml" Target="../customXml/item2.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId21" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/webSettings" Target="webSettings.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId12" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId17" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header4.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/customXml" Target="../customXml/item1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId16" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image1.PNG"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId20" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/fontTable" Target="fontTable.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/keyMapCustomizations" Target="customizations.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Target="settings.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId11" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header2.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId15" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer3.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId10" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId19" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer4.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/numbering" Target="numbering.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId9" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/endnotes" Target="endnotes.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId14" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header3.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

This is the python code I am using:

```
sourceXmlDoc = etree.parse(DOCUMENT_XML_PATH)

# open the document.xml.rels file
documentRelation = etree.parse(DOC_XML_RELS_PATH)

results = documentRelation.findall('//Relationship')
```

The results list returned is 0 in length though.

Comment: There is a default namespace. It should work with `documentRelation.findall('//{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships}Relationship')` or `documentRelation.findall('//{*}Relationship')`.

Comment: Oh thanks!!! Including the namespace worked!

Comment: Or `documentRelation.findall('//doc:Relationship', namespaces={'doc': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'})` and using `lxml` replace `findall` with `xpath` and run any complex XPath 1.0 queries.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has landed here looking for the answer to this exact question except using **PHP**, this is a **solution**:

```
$xpath->registerNameSpace('default','http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships');
$doc_nodes = $xpath->query( "//any_namespace_name:Relationship" );
```